# Remove unused functions from shared library

Tags: linker, shared-libraries

Consider the following files:

foo.c

```c
void
bar(void);

void
foo(void)
{
    bar();
}
```

bar.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void
bar(void)
{
    printf("bar\n");
}

void
baz(void)
{
    printf("baz\n");
}
```

vis.map

```
{
    global:
        foo;
    local:
        *;
};
```

I've compiled them into a library by

```bash
gcc -c -ffunction-sections foo.c
gcc -c -ffunction-sections bar.c
gcc -Wl,--version-script,vis.map -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o bar.o
```

As expected, `nm -D libfoo.so` shows only the `foo` symbol.  However, `objdump -d libfoo.so` shows the code for `baz`.  I would have thought, given that it's unreachable from the only visible function, that the linker would have removed `baz` from the final output.

Is there a linker flag or something to accomplish this?

For context, bar.c represents code from another project that I'm trying to use in my project.  So, it's infeasible to alter it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--gc-sections` linker flag does the trick.  According to [`man ld`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html), it

> [enables] garbage collection of unused input sections.

Since you're compiling with `-ffunction-sections`, each function will be put into its own section.  Adding `-Wl,--gc-sections` to your final `gcc` invocation will remove the unused `baz` section.